# How to ignore word delimiters in sed

Tags: regex, bash, sed

So I have a bash script which is working perfectly except for one issue with sed.

```
full=$(echo $full | sed -e 's/\b'$first'\b/ /' -e 's/  / /g')
```

This would work great except there are instances where the variable $first is preceeded immediately by a period, not a blank space.  In those instances, I do not want the variable removed.

Example:

```
full="apple.orange orange.banana apple.banana banana";first="banana"
full=$(echo $full | sed -e 's/\b'$first'\b/ /' -e 's/  / /g')
echo $first $full;
```

I want to only remove the whole word banana, and not make any change to orange.banana or apple.banana, so how can I get sed to ignore the dot as a delimiter?

Comment: What other characters immediately before `banana` count for removal? Just spaces? Spaces and all other non-word characters *except* period?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want "banana" that is preceded by beginning-of-string or a space, and followed by a space or end-of-string

```
$ sed -r 's/(^|[[:blank:]])'"$first"'([[:blank:]]|$)/ /g' <<< "$full"
apple.orange orange.banana apple.banana
```

Note the use of `-r` option (for bsd sed, use `-E`) that enables extended regular expressions -- allow us to omit a lot of backslashes.

Comment: Plus1 for providing the solution AND quoting the variable :-)!

Comment: I did a little testing after initially reviewing your response, noticed I didn't include the -r option along with the other changes you provided.  With that, it's definitely working as needed.